# Same results for both ACF and PACF with Strange plot when I forecast

Tags: r, time-series, stationarity

I have two questions. The first one is related with the ACF and PACF and the second with the Resulted Plot after using sarima.for
I have downloaded the bitcoin price for the last 3 years as an example to learn how to do time-series analysis.

Then as you can see I took the first difference and the lag in order to detrend and remove variance.

[image]

How can I interpret the following case?

This is my model:

fit2 <- sarima(Ret.Bit,2,1,2)

with

```
> $ttable
         Estimate     SE  t.value p.value
ar1       -0.7751 0.0221 -35.1251  0.0000
ar2       -0.9381 0.0175 -53.7412  0.0000
ma1        0.7410 0.0158  46.9190  0.0000
ma2        0.9672 0.0134  72.1050  0.0000
constant   2.4933 1.3152   1.8957  0.0582
```

Using `sarima.for(Ret.Bit,n.ahead = 4,2,1,2` I ve got this strange plot.
[image]

For me, it is strange both the dates, 1560 etc, and the fact that going out of the plot the line. 
Please, any help suggestion?

Comment: The "strange plot" bit is a question about software and off-topic here, and it is not answerable because you did not provide a reproducible example (including describing which package `sarima.for` is from, and the type of the variable `Ret.Bit`, which I'm guessing is wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the acf of the original series = acf of the residual series your model has self-cancelling structure thus equivalent to a (0,0,0)(0,0,0,) . This is a great example of using VERY BAD software to "identify" a model. Sometimes software is worth what you pay for it. Notice how the ar coefficients are eerily similar to the ma coefficients.

Comment: The orders aren't identified by the software, they were supplied in the function call.

Comment: @Chris Haug  ..Thanks for the correction. My faith in free software has been (partially !) restored. It would be interesting to me if the OP explained how they assumed the model or just saw it in a book/post somewhere and decided to go with it without understanding the consequences.